# Using the CSS3 :not selector with IE - using Prototype

Tags: css, css-selectors, prototypejs

I need to add a CSS style to a content `<div>`, which is present on all pages of my site. However, I do not want to use the new style on the homepage.

All the pages on the site have a similar structure: a header `<div>` with navigation bar, followed by a content `<div>` with the page's contents.

Best I could think of is to add a wrapper div directly under the content div on the homepage, like so...

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="homepage_content">
      ....homepage content....
```

Then I can apply my style to the entire content `<div>` using the `:not` selector, so the elements under `homepage_content` are not included.

This won't work in IE. I've seen jQuery workarounds for it, but we are using Prototype on my site.

Anyone have an idea for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOT is in fact [not an option yet](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

There are certainly Prototype based workarounds for this as well, but a pure CSS solution would probably be much preferable.

Maybe a workaround by adding another, invisible container around the other objects is an option?

```
<div id="content">
   <div class="other_elements">
    .... the other elements you want to style ....
   </div>
   <div id="homepage_content">
      ....homepage content....
</div>
```

and then addressing the other objects like

```
#content .other_elements elementname {  ...... }
```

whether this is possible, will depend on your CSS structure.

Comment: Pekka, adding an invisible container around all other objects would mean editing every other page on the site!

Comment: unless... i can check in php if the current page is the homepage, and if not, echo the container div... what do you think?

Comment: btw, :not is supported by every current modern browser, other than IE

Comment: @esther ah, I didn't catch this. Hmm, in that case, it may be easiest to add a class to the container element when it's *not* the homepage: `<div id="content" class="subpage">` and then address `#content.subpage` in the CSS

Comment: @esther re every modern browser, true.... But sadly, supporting IE is mandatory for most sites

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following HTML on the home page:

```
<div id="content" class="home-page">
```

And the following HTML on every other page:

```
<div id="content" class="regular-page">
```

Then add your CSS style like this:

```
#content.regular-page {
    /* Styles here */
}
```

Comment: yes, i ended up doing something like that... i used php to check which page i am on to know which class to give it...